# Can't connect to internet via wireless wifi

Tags: networking

I'm "trying" kubuntu 22.04.1 from a dvd.  That is I haven't actually installed it. It seems to be running OK but I can't connect to internet via wireless wifi. I'm lost on how to set up the connection. Documentation points me to things that don't seem to exist.

Comment: what does the documentation point you to that doesn't seem to exist?

Comment: I would write the 22.04.1 ISO to thumb-drive and "try* Kubuntu from there if you can.  Ubuntu no longer aims for *optical media* installations, and you can experience *timeouts* due to extra time caused by your use of DVD (or *optical*) media that can cause your system to experience errors you won't have post-install. That may not be your issue, but unless you've checked your system logs it may also be. Normal wifi troubleshooting details can be found [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessTroubleShootingGuide) where 3. *Device Recognition and Operation* will most useful.

Comment: Do note: the link I provided assumes Ubuntu Desktop (not Kubuntu), but the same applies to all *flavors* of Ubuntu (ie. to Kubuntu) as we all use the same underneath Ubuntu infrastructure.

Comment: Ester - https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-wireless-connect.html.en  System menu wasn't where it said it was.  The menu I found didn't name any networks.

Comment: guiverc_- Yeah, I was thinking the same thing.   Running an OS from anything other than a hard disk is something I'm still on a learning curve with.

Comment: I run *live* systems (including with *persistence* on occasion) from thumb-drives very regularly without issue, but I'd **not** use a DVD unless it was purely for QA (*Quality Assurance*) purposes, the last time being to confirm the issues with DVD post-groovy (20.10) changes & to ensure install was still possible. Adding kernel modules (aka *drivers*) to a *live* system (regardless of media) is always harder, so *live* or not-installed is easiest with *generic* hardware with mainstream (*enterprise*) hardware (less so *consumer* grade unless very common).

Comment: I found the troubleshoot page on my own.  (thanks anyway) .  I didn't get a connected response.  I did find that the machine knows it has a card (PCIE).  I got indications it has a driver.  I suspect though it's not working because it's a windows driver.  I haven't yet figured out how to install a driver to test that.  While trying to set up a wireless connection I had blank fields that I didn't know how to fill.  SSID and such.

Comment: *Drivers* are actually kernel modules; thus are built for specific kernels (why a windows 7 driver may not work on 8 or 10 etc), so you need a kernel module (aka *driver*) for the 5.15 kernel used by Kubuntu 22.04 LTS. If talking about a printer driver, as many are just text files they will work on any OS/system (macOS, Ubuntu or windows), but hardware drivers are built for a specific kernel. Drivers are made for the chipset on the hardware they control; 3.1 on https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessTroubleShootingGuide is where I'd start (for Ubuntu & all flavors inc. Kubuntu)

Comment: Hey, the thumb drive worked for what ever reason.  Boot from that and a wifi icon shows up at the bottom right.  Put in a password and all is right with the world.  Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

I suggested (*in comment*) I would write the 22.04.1 ISO to thumb-drive and "*Try*" Kubuntu from there if you can. Ubuntu no longer aims for *optical media* installations, and you can experience *timeouts* due to extra time caused by your use of DVD (or optical) media that can cause your system to experience errors you won't have post-install.

*These issues are seen in logs, so you need to explore system logs at terminal to recognize/confirm this. You can re-try the boot & install & next time it may work (it works flawlessly about 33% of the time in my own [rather limited] QA) with it failing if timeout is reached before data is read. The GUI messages post-timeout are not helpful though & only make sense if the full system logs are read and you recognize the subsequent error was because of optical-read timeout*.

The OP confirmed it was (*as I read it*) related to the *optical installation media* which is not intended for releases past Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.  This answer just to *close* the question.

> Hey, the thumb drive worked for what ever reason. Boot from that and a
> wifi icon shows up at the bottom right. Put in a password and all is
> right with the world. Thanks all.

Comment: this answer is just copy/pasted from my prior comments, with some edits & expansion; alas mostly my opinion as result of QA.  The 33% may vary on hardware, both CPU & optical drive & my testing was limited to only a few dell & hp devices, none of which are *newish*.